# Nagios, reset MySQL password

Tags: nagios, debian-squeeze

I accedently reset the MySQL root password for the nagios user, it now is trying to connect to the database, however it cannot actually get in since the password is wrong.

Where does nagios safe the MySQL password or where can I change it ?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since u are talking about MySQL and nagios I assume u are using ndo2db.

If that is the case, check your ndo2db.cfg file. It should be in there.

Answer (score 1):

Check `resource.cfg` in your Nagios configuration directory.